# ISO currency list

Tags: spring, jquery-plugins, spring-mvc, currency

I am developing a web app and I need to show all the currencies in the dropdown list.I am sure many people have done this before. I was wondering whats the best way to achieve this? Is there a jquery plugin that will give me a list of available currencies? Do I need to get the list from somewhere and store data in mysql table, if so, is there such reference table available ?

Tech Stack

Sprng MVC 3.0
Hibernate

Thanks

Comment: Is there a service that sends out update regarding changes in the currency? For example addition on new currency etc ...

Answer (score 8):

The ISO web site [links](http://www.iso.org/iso/home/standards/currency_codes.htm) to the Web site of [the ISO 4217 Maintenance agency](http://www.currency-iso.org/en/home/tables/table-a1.html). The latter has the list of currencies in XLS and XML formats, along with names, codes etc. You could use that to populate your reference data.

Now, there are 281 codes. Whether sticking them all into a drop-down box would result in usable UI remains to be seen.